# Spring Boot : Building object Rest API

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I created 4 classes for 3 tables. Those tables are built to store orders with products.

**My first entity is orders :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity seller;

    private String paymentMode;

    private double totalAmount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.order")
    private List<OrderProductEntity> orderProducts;

    @DateTimeFormat
    private Date createdAt;

    ... 
}
```

**My second entity is products:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@Getter @Setter
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String productKeyId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int availableQty;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Valid
    private List<OrderProductEntity> orderProducts;
    ...
}
```

**I also define the pivot table in the OrderProductEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_product")
@Getter @Setter
public class OrderProductEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    private OrderProductPK pk;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer quantity;

    // default constructor
    public OrderProductEntity(){}
    public OrderProductEntity(OrderEntity order, ProductEntity product, Integer quantity) {
        pk = new OrderProductPK();
        pk.setOrder(order);
        pk.setProduct(product);
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

And I defined the PK of this table :

```
@Embeddable
@Getter @Setter
public class OrderProductPK implements Serializable {
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private OrderEntity order;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductEntity product;
}
```

Now my issue is to return the data to the front office by a web service Rest. 
I created a model that represent what i want to obtain as result.

```
public class OrderRest {
    private String orderKeyId;
    private String paymentMode;
    private double totalAmount;
    private List<ProductRest> orderProducts;
    private UserRest seller;
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

And :

```
public class ProductRest {
    private String productKeyId;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int qty;
    private String imgPath;
    private CategoryRest category;
}
```

In my controller i want to return an OrderRest object :

```
public List<OrderRest> getOrders() {
    List<OrderRest> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    List<OrderDto> orderDtos = orderService.getOrders();

    // loop the result
    for (OrderDto orderDto : orderDtos) {
        OrderRest orderRest = new OrderRest();
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        orderRest = modelMapper.map(orderDto, OrderRest.class);
        returnValue.add(orderRest);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

THis method map the List of OrderRest and call the service layer :

```
public List<OrderDto> getOrders() {
    List<OrderDto> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterable<OrderEntity> orderEntities = orderRepository.findAll();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    for(OrderEntity orderEntity: orderEntities) {
        OrderDto orderDto = new OrderDto();
        UserDto userDto = orderDto.getSeller();
        List<OrderProductDto> orderProductDtos  = orderDto.getOrderProducts();

        orderDto = modelMapper.map(orderEntity, OrderDto.class);
        returnValue.add(orderDto);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

With OrderDto :

```
public class OrderDto implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String orderKeyId;
    private String paymentMode;
    private double totalAmount;
    private List<OrderProductDto> orderProducts;
    private UserDto seller;
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

And OrderProductDto :

```
public class OrderProductDto implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String productKeyId;
    private String name;
    private Integer price;
    private Integer qty;
    private String imgPath;
    private CategoryDto category;
}
```

My issue is concerning what i return from the REST API : 
my product list returns nothing :

```
"orderProducts": [
     {
         "productKeyId": null,
         "name": null,
         "price": 0.0,
         "qty": 0,
         "imgPath": null,
         "category": null
     },...
]
```

Comment: Where's the code for ModelMapper?

Comment: @Smutje, I can suggest, that he use this lib http://modelmapper.org.
This lib available in maven repos    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper

Comment: model mapper allow to map different objects. it copies my rest object in DTO object then entity objects to DTO .. at then end i expect to recover a Rest object as response. it's a most advanced library than BeanUtils.copyProperties() ...